# Rolling Regression over several columns with NA´s

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to run multiple rolling-window regressions and saving the betas for each regression.
My dataset (df) is quite large (577 rows; 15000 columns) and looks something as follows:

```
         date  Inflation  RET.1  RET.2  RET.3  RET.4  RET.5          
    1    2020    1.22      0.28  -0.21    NA   0.11   0.01
    2    2019    1.12      0.11  -0.11    NA   0.03   0.21    
    3    2018    1.52      0.24  -0.71    NA   0.91   0.01    
    4    2017    1.26      0.38  -0.41  -0.21   NA    0.21
    5    2016    0.22      0.74  -0.28   0.61   NA    0.07
    6    2015    1.62       NA     NA   -0.12  0.47   0.41
    7    2014    1.28       NA     NA    0.34  0.31   0.12
    8    2013    1.21       NA     NA   -0.56  -0.1   0.25
```

In my given example I want to regress the columns RET.1 through RET.5 on Inflation (lm(RET.1 ~ Inflation);lm(RET.2 ~ Inflation)...) for the first 3 observations. Then save the beta (slope coefficient). Then run on the next 3 (so Row 2 to Row 4) and save the next beta. I want to do this 5 times for my different RET values and the regression should only to be exercised if there are no missing values in the three observations, else return NA.

What I would like to get is thus something along the following lines:

```
Date  RET.1  RET.2  RET.3  RET.4  RET.5
2020  coef   coef   NA     coef   coef
2019  coef   coef   NA      NA    coef
2018  coef   coef   NA      NA    coef
2017   NA    NA    coef     NA    coef
2016   NA    NA    coef     NA    coef
```

I wanted to loop the roll_regres function (@Benjamin Christoffersen:thx for creating this awesome function!) over the RET.1-5 columns for this. As a test, I first applied the roll_regress function only to the RET.1 column using the following code:

```
betas <- roll_regres(RET.1 ~ Inflation, df, width = 3, do_downdates=TRUE, min_obs = 3)
```

This however returns:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(RET.1 = c(0.28, 0.11,  : 
  missing values in object
```

It seems like the default roll_regres function has an issue handling the NA´s.
Does anyone have a solution as to how to conduct the roll_regres function with missing values and to then loop it?
Or maybe this is not the right approach and there is a better way around this?

Very grateful already. All the best

Rose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the data in the Note at the end and the fact that cov(x, y) / var(x) gives the slope of regressing y against x.  If y is a data frame it gives the slopes for each column.  The body of the slopes function is similar to `coef(lm(as.matrix(Y) ~ x, subset = ix))[2, ]` but handles NA's in the desired manner.

```
library(zoo)

w <- 3
nms <- startsWith(names(DF), "RET")
slopes <- function(ix, x, Y) cov(x = x[ix], y = Y[ix,]) / var(x[ix])
betas <- rollapply(1:nrow(DF), w, slopes, align = "left", 
  x = DF$Inflation, Y = DF[nm])
replace(head(DF, -(w-1)), nms, betas)  # combine DF and betas
```

giving:

```
  date Inflation      RET.1     RET.2      RET.3    RET.4        RET.5
1 2020      1.22  0.2192308 -1.538462         NA 2.307692 -0.384615385
2 2019      1.12  0.2160194 -1.456311         NA       NA -0.533980583
3 2018      1.52 -0.3736264 -0.271978         NA       NA  0.005494505
4 2017      1.26         NA        NA -0.5809788       NA  0.218718466
5 2016      0.22         NA        NA -0.4578020       NA  0.196174044
6 2015      1.62         NA        NA  0.3014553 1.097713  0.537422037
```

We double check the first value in the RET.2 column of the output:

```
coef(lm(RET.2 ~ Inflation, DF, subset = 1:3))[[2]] 
## [1] -1.538462
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(date = 2020:2013, Inflation = c(1.22, 1.12, 1.52, 
1.26, 0.22, 1.62, 1.28, 1.21), RET.1 = c(0.28, 0.11, 0.24, 0.38, 
0.74, NA, NA, NA), RET.2 = c(-0.21, -0.11, -0.71, -0.41, -0.28, 
NA, NA, NA), RET.3 = c(NA, NA, NA, -0.21, 0.61, -0.12, 0.34, 
-0.56), RET.4 = c(0.11, 0.03, 0.91, NA, NA, 0.47, 0.31, -0.1), 
    RET.5 = c(0.01, 0.21, 0.01, 0.21, 0.07, 0.41, 0.12, 0.25)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```